# Método con llamada Axios se ejecuta una vez termina el método padre

Tags: vue.js, laravel-8, axios

Tengo la siguiente problemática:

Estoy utilizando fullcalendar para la gestión de appointments. Para manejar de mejor manera los datos del calendar utilizo un método prepareData(que transforma la data al formato que estoy trabajando) y otro método searchProfessorName, para realizar la búsqueda del nombre del profesor que tiene asignada dicha tarea. Hasta ahí, todo bien.

El problema aparece cuando realizo el llamado del método searchProfessorName dentro del método prepare data. Adjunto como lo tengo escrito.

```
 for (let i = 0; i < this.allEvents.length; i++) {
        const professor_id = this.allEvents[i]._def.extendedProps.professor_id;
        const room_vcode = this.allEvents[i]._def.extendedProps.room_vcode;
        const event = this.allEvents[i]._def.extendedProps;

        console.log("tengo el professor_id y el room_vcode");
        this.searchProfessorName(professor_id);
        this.searchRoomName(room_vcode);

        let obj = {
          index: i,
          vcode: event.vcode,
          code: event.code,
          name: event.name,
          group: event.group,
          type: event.type,
          professor: this.professor_name,
          room: this.room_vcode,
          professor_id: event.professor_id,
          room_vcode: event.room_vcode,
          duration: event.duration,
          start: Moment(this.allEvents[i].start).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"),
          end: Moment(this.allEvents[i].end).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"),
        };

        console.log(obj);

        this.data.push(obj);
        console.log(this.data);
      }
```

el método searchProfessorName:

```
searchProfessorName: function (professor_id) {
      axios
        .get(
          route("users.getNameProfessor", {
            professor_id,
          })
        )
        .then((response) => {
          console.log("Buscando Nombre professor");
          this.professor_name = response.data[0].name;
          console.log(this.professor_name);
        });
    },
```

Todo se ejecuta correctamente, pero desconozco porque el método searchProfessorName se ejecuta una vez termina el método prepareData. Por lo que, me prepara los datos con el atributo professor(que es el nombre del profesor) y room_name como undefined

Comment: ¿searchNameUser es searchProfessorName? es algo confuso que manejes los dos nombres en tu pregunta

Comment: si, lo corregiré ahora